# Meteor-react passing variable to child container

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I’m working on an app where users can make comments, and others can reply to their comment (reply).

My problem is that when I pass the commentId to the ReplyDetail component (the child) I’m unable to access the commentId as a prop in the createContainer - I can only access it in the component. I am looping (map) through the comments.

This is how I am passing the variable from commentContent.jsx (inside the map function)

```js
<div className="section">
    <ReplyDetail commentId={comment._id} 
</div>
```

And this is the child component replyDetail.jsx

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import { Comments } from '../../../imports/collections/groupMethods';

class ReplyDetail extends Component {

 render() {

  //this works
  const commentId = this.props.commentId;
  console.log('this.props.commentId ' + this.props.commentId);

  return(
       <div>{commentId}</div>
        )
 }
}

export default createContainer((props) => {
 Meteor.subscribe('comments');

 //this doesn't work
  const commentId = this.props.commentId;
  console.log('this.props.commentId-2 ' + this.props.commentId);
  return { 
     };
}, ReplyDetail)
```

And this is the error I get.

> Warning: There is an internal error in the React performance
>   measurement code. Did not expect componentDidMount timer to start
>   while componentWillMount timer is still in progress for another
>   instance.

I need the replies to be reactive, so how do I either pass the commentId (props) directly to the container - or how can I pass the commentId from the component to the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, It doesn't work because your `createContainer` function already receives the props in the argument `(props)` so you don't need `this.` 
This should fix:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Comments } from '../../../imports/collections/groupMethods';

class ReplyDetail extends Component {

render() {
    const {commentId} = this.props;
    console.log('commentId', commentId);
    return (
        <div>{commentId}</div>
    )
  }
}

export default createContainer((props) => {
    Meteor.subscribe('comments');
    const commentId = props.commentId;
    console.log('commentIdFromContainer', commentId);
  return { 

  };
}, ReplyDetail)
```

Comment: Brilliant - thanks @ilan Hasanov - works like a charm :)